# How to use combineReducers with handleActions

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js, redux-actions, redux-immutable

I'm trying to create new reducer `survey`, which must combine `name` and `questions` reducers while using `handleActions` from `redux-actions` package. But I recieve an error `Invariant Violation: Expected handlers to be a plain object.` How should I change it to actually work?

```
import { Map, List } from 'immutable';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions';

const initialNameState = List();
const initialQuestionsState = List();

const name = handleActions({}, initialNameState);
const questions = handleActions({}, initialQuestionsState);

export const initialSurveyState = Map({
  name: initialNameState,
  questions: initialQuestionsState
});

export const survey = handleActions(
  combineReducers({
    name,
    questions
  }),
  initialSurveyState
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleAction` actually creates a reducer. Directly using `combineReducer` should solve the problem.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Map, List } from 'immutable';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { handleActions, createAction, combineActions } from 'redux-actions';

const initialNameState = List();
const initialQuestionsState = List();

const name = handleActions({}, initialNameState);
const questions = handleActions({}, initialQuestionsState);

export const survey = combineReducers({name, questions});

const store = createStore(survey);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I'm still wondering if it can work without existing actions. I have many reducers which will handle different actions in the next stages of the development. Should I create dumb actions for them?

Answer (score 0):

try this  and tell me if it work or not

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

const initialNameState = List();
const initialQuestionsState = List();

const name = handleActions({}, initialNameState);
const questions = handleActions({}, initialQuestionsState);

 const initialSurveyState = Map({
  name: initialNameState,
  questions: initialQuestionsState
});
    export const rootReducer=combineReducers({
    name,
    questions
  })

  const store=createStore(rootReducer)
```

Comment: It works, the problem was in not using combineReducers directly, thanks